# Javascript regexp to split a string both ways

Tags: javascript, regex, split

```
    var REGEX = new RegExp("(?=[hms])g")

    var TIME = _GET('t', '0').split(REGEX)

    var hours = TIME[TIME.indexOf('h')-1]

    var minutes = TIME[TIME.indexOf('m')-1]

    var seconds = TIME[TIME.indexOf('s')-1]

    var HOURS = hours?('hours: '+hours):''

    var MINUTES = minutes?('minutes: '+minutes):''

    var SECONDS = seconds?('seconds: '+seconds):''

    document.write('TIME RECIEVED:<br><br>'+HOURS+'<br>'+MINUTES+'<br>'+SECONDS)
```

this is the entire code. I basically wanted to see if I could mimick youtube's video trick (put &t=XhYmZs to go to that time in a video)

The only missing thing is that I don't know regular expressions >_<

What I need is to split the string `"5h55m55s"` into `['5','h','55','m','55','s']` instead of `['5', 'h55', 'm55', 's']`, which is breaks my code. Oh yeah, and the _GET function is unimportant, it just obtains a string from the url, like php's $_GET variable

So Obviously, the regex `/(?=[hms])/` doesn't work completely and I need to know how to get it to split both on the "left" and "right" of `h`, `m`, and `s`

Basically, the answer to this question is a regexp that splits, for example, `"55m55s"` into the array `['55','m','55','s']`

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Um2cw/1/)here is the _GET function I use, if you were curious. It's used like so: `_GET('q', 'no value returned')`. If you type `?q=john doe` in the addressbar, it will return `"john%20doe"`, which can be easily fixed by instead putting `_GET('q','no value returned').replace(/%20/g, ' ')` (will return `"john doe"`). The second parameter in the function allows for default (nothing was typed in address bar), in that case, it returns `'no value returned'`. I find it to be a very convenient function :P

Comment: Downvoting without giving a reason is unconstructive and wastes the reputation of both parties. This question was posted 5 years ago. Yes, it's poorly written, but what do you expect me to do about it *now*? Rewrite it? What good would that do? The question has more problems than just the way it is written. Delete it? That's not good practice--what if someone finds it useful? What lesson am I supposed to learn from having a 5 year old question get downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could something like...

```
var parts = "5h55m55s"
   .split(/(\d+)/).filter(function(a) { return a; });
   // ["5", "h", "55", "m", "55", "s"]
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Buus9/).

This will drop times of `0`. If that is possible, change the `filter()` body to `return a.length`.

Comment: thanks :D I ran it in my browser's dev tools (`TIME.toString().split(/(\d+)/)` returned `['', 'm', 55', s, '55']`)

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hDgre/) here is a jsfiddle compatible version of the final script. It's just like youtube's `&t=XmYs` trick

Answer (score 1):

```
var pieces = "55m55s".match(/\d+|[hms]/g);
// ["55", "m", "55", "s"]

var pieces = "5h55m55s".match(/\d+|[hms]/g);
// ["5", "h", "55", "m", "55", "s"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
time = "5h55m55s";
pattern = /(\d*h)(\d*m)(\d*s)/i
timeArry=time.match(pattern);
console.log(timeArry.splice(1,3));​ //Output ["5h", "55m", "55s"]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eteuz/

Comment: That's not what I was trying to do :/

Answer (score 0):

To do it with a regular expression:

```
var regex = /(\d+)h(\d+)m(\d+)s/g
var time = _GET('t', '0').match(regex)
var hours = time[0]
var minutes = time[1]
var seconds = time[2]
var HOURS = hours ? ('hours: ' + hours) : ''
var MINUTES = minutes ? ('minutes: ' + minutes) : ''
var SECONDS = seconds ? ('seconds: ' + seconds) : ''
document.write('time RECIEVED:<br><br>' + HOURS + '<br>' + MINUTES + '<br>' + SECONDS)​
```

`(\d+)h` finds digits that precede a literal `h` character.

`(\d+)m` finds digits that precede a literal `m` character.

`(\d+)s` finds digits that precede a literal `s` character.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I've come a long way.

I had to implement something like this some time ago, and the answer is actually really simple. Nonetheless, it reminded me of this question.

So, to answer my own question, here's what I cooked up:

```
function parseTime(t){
  var h = RegExp('([0-9]*)h').exec(t),
      m = RegExp('([0-9]*)m').exec(t),
      s = RegExp('([0-9]*)s').exec(t),
      a = [];
  if(h){
    a.push('Hours: '+h[1]);
  }
  if(m){
    a.push('Minutes: '+m[1]);
  }
  if(s){
    a.push('Seconds: '+s[1]);
  }
  return a;
}

parseTime('1h23m45s'); // ['Hours: 1', 'Minutes: 23', 'Seconds: 45']
parseTime('1h45s');    // ['Hours: 1', 'Seconds: 45']
parseTime('2m')        // ['Minutes: 2']
```

It's simple and dynamic. Plus, to read it out is as simple as:

```
var _time = parseTime('12m14s');
console.log(_time.join('\n'));
```

Which prints

```
Minutes: 12
Seconds: 14
```